# How to make natural scrolling work in all applications

Tags: nautilus, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I have enabled natural scrolling for the wireless mouse using xinput

```
xinput set-button-map 11 1 2 3 5 4 7 6
```

This works well in almost all apps with notable exception Nautilus and last version of Chrome. For the touchpad I enabled natural scrolling through settings and it works in Nautilus and Chrome as well.
How can I make it work in all applications for wireless mouse also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like GTK was using a different input for mouse. See [this blog post](https://andym3.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/fixing-natural-scrolling-in-ubuntu-12-04/) for a detailed description.

I had to use `xinput set-prop`:

```
xinput set-prop 11 278 -1, -1, -1
```